# How to write to specific blocks to eMMC multiple times to check the number of read/write cycles

Tags: memory, hardware-failure, analysis

I am looking forward to read/write to a particular block in eMMC repeatedly till it fails. I have an embedded device with Debian Linux running on it.

I have seen options such as `dd` command, but how do I control the exact physical block to which I will be writing chunks of data, and repeat the process, to see the number read/write cycles till failure of the block ?

Comment: I am afraid to leave this comment, but what operating system are you using,  what tools you have at your disposal is an important consideration.

Comment: Most SSDs and MMCs do not allow direct hardware control the way previous HDDs did. The OS does not actually know the exact address of any bit of data on the new drives. I'm guessing this is actually impossible outside of custom hardware/software built by the SSD manufacturers.